# Maximum period-length in decimal chain-addition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, cryptography, periodic-functions

Decimal *chain-addition* $^*$ takes a finite initial "seed" string of decimal digits, say $x_1x_2...x_n$, and defines an infinite periodic string $x_1x_2...x_n...$ by iterating the following rewrite rule, taking the leftmost digit as output each time:
$$x_1x_2...x_n\ \ \to \ \ x_2...x_nx_{n+1}$$
where $x_{n+1}= (x_1 + x_2)\ (\mathrm{mod\ 10})$. In the form of a recursion this is
$$x_{n+k} = (x_k + x_{k+1})\ (\mathrm{mod\ 10}),\ \ k\ge 1.
$$
For example, starting with seed $528$, the procedure defines an infinite string $(5287057522...8593427693)^\omega$ that has a period of length $168$:

$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{5}28}&\\
\to\ \mathbf{2}8&7\tag{1}\\
\to\ \mathbf{8}&70\tag{2}\\
\to\ &\mathbf{7}05\tag{3}\\
&  ...\\
& \to \mathbf{3}52\tag{167}\\
& \ \ \to \color{blue}{\mathbf{5}28}\tag{168}\\
& \ \quad ...
\end{align}
$$

> **Question**: Is there a way (other than brute force computation) to determine  the maximum period-length produced by seeds of a given length?

There seems to be an extensive literature on *binary* variants of this procedure (mostly related to pseudorandom number generators), under the names *linear feedback shift register* and *lagged Fibonacci generator*, but I don't see applications to the decimal case.

EDIT (per the comments): Among $n$-long seeds, $0^{n-1}1$ must produce a maximum-length period. Here are some results of my brute force computations, all using seed $0^{n-1}1$:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\text{Seed length, }n & \text{Maximum period-length, }l_{max} & \text{Prime factorization of }l_{max} \\
\hline
2 &             60 & 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot  5\\
3 &            168 & 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot     7\\
4 &           1560 & 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot  5 \cdot        13\\
5 &          16401 &           3 \cdot     7 \cdot 11\cdot                71\\
6 &         196812 & 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot   7 \cdot 11\cdot                71\\
7 &         661416 & 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot     7 \cdot               31\cdot          127\\
8 &          15624 & 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot   7 \cdot               31\\
9 &        8894028 & 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot        11 \cdot 13\cdot            71\cdot  73\\
10&     1736327236 & 2^2 \cdot       7 \cdot           19\cdot  31\cdot          127\cdot     829\\
11&     3712686852 & 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot     7 \cdot               31\cdot      73\cdot             19531\\
12&      203450520 & 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot  5 \cdot 7\cdot      13\cdot        31\cdot                601\\
13&    25732419240 & 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot  5 \cdot    11\cdot      17\cdot    31\cdot  71\cdot         521\\
14& 14417724597564 & 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot                      31\cdot          127\cdot             305175781\\
\end{array}$$

$^*$Decimal chain-addition was actually part of the ["hollow nickel" cipher](https://www.cia.gov/library/center-for-the-study-of-intelligence/kent-csi/vol5no4/html/v05i4a09p_0001.htm) exposed in the 1950s.

Comment: Note that there _cannot_ ever be any length-$n$ seed with a _longer_ period than that of $0^{n-1}1$, since the recurrence is linear and every seed is a linear combination of shifted copies of $0^{n-1}1$ (which are the first $n$ iterations of the seed $1,0^{n-1}$ and therefore all have the same period). So every possible period for a seed of length $n$ is a divisor of the period length of $0^{n-1}1$.

Comment: And that again mean that you can compute the period in base 10 as the least common multiple of the periods in base 2 and base 5, thanks to the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Thanks for the comments. I had totally missed the fact that the period-length of any $n$-long seed must be a divisor of the period-length of $0^{n-1}1$!